# Piers Anthony Book Cross-Overs?

Tags: crossovers, piers-anthony, xanth

I enjoy all of Brandon Sanderson's novels and I know he's doing the whole 'Cosmere' thing. I'm looking forward to spotting the cross-overs there.

Well, I was recently on the Jim Butcher forum and saw them asking about crossovers and whether people were just imagining it, because crossovers are in vogue now, or whether there was anything intentional on the authors part. I'm sure many authors do a little cross-over now and then, even if no one but them will recognize it. They probably don't set out to do anything as intentionally ambitious as Brandon Sanderson.

I'm currently re-reading the Xanth series, because I haven't read the last 7 books or so. I'm almost done and I'm starting book 35, with 4 more to go. I know there has been some cross-over with at least one other series. I first saw it in 'Cube Route' I believe. The characters entered a painting and while they never came out and said it, this was the world of Phaze and characters from there. This is from Pier's other series "The Apprentice Adept", which I also enjoyed.

I just finished reading 'Knot Gneiss' and saw another cross-over, where the characters encountered BEMs (aka Bug Eyed Monsters). These are aliens that appear in the Adept series as well.

My question is, does anyone know of any other crossover events in any of Pier's Anthony's series. I haven't read them all and I usually get immersed in whatever I'm reading, so I might not notice it unless it smacks me in the face. These may be the only two instances where he does something like this, but I was curious of if anyone else knew what crossovers he's done. Thanks.

Comment: This is a list question, but one with a finite set of answers, so we should be good. :)

Comment: Thanks. I tried to phrase it in a way where there weren't a large number of possible answers.

Answer (score 2):

From the Wikipedia article for [The Mode Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_series):

> The Mode series makes a referential crossover into the Xanth series in Question Quest, where the Good Magician Humfrey makes a note in his book about Darius being the "Cyng of Hlahtar".

And [this review for *Tarot*](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0441798411) mentions that

> It is also closely related with another series of Anthony's, with a crossover in fact for the fifth book in the Cluster Cycle, "Viscious Circle."

In fact, it seems that Piers Anthony intended *[The Cluster Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_(novels)#Relationship_with_other_novels)* to be in the same setting as both the *Tarot* books and *But What of Earth?*..

Comment: That's good. I've read the Mode series, and I think I remembered that from Question Quest standing out to me, but I didn't place it or make the connection. I've never read the Tarot series.

Comment: @Dalton: So far, it looks like the ones you mentioned, and the Question Quest / Mode crossover, are the only ones I can find. The latter one that I mention looks like they're simply intended to be books set in the same series.

Answer (score 1):

In *Question Quest*, Humfrey mentions Stile from *The Apprentice Adept*, Zane from *The Incarnations of Immortality*, Kelvin from *The Adventures of Kelvin of Rud*, and Darius from the *Mode* series.

Cube and several Xanthian characters traveled to Phaze where they met Drek and several other characters in *Cube Route* from *The Apprentice Adept* series.

In *DoOne Mode* the characters are in Xanth for a chapter and Metria makes an appearance.